# Maven build fails: package does not exist

Tags: java, maven

I'm having a strange problem where I have one maven project that has a dependency on another maven project (both are mine) and I'm getting a compilation error complaining that packages don't exist - even though they do.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.424 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-22T07:32:51-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project e1-task-info2: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/jgagnon/workspace/java/e1-task-info2/src/main/java/com/mycompany/e1tasks/backend/util/ExcelFileIngester.java:[10,42] package com.mycompany.exceljson.converter does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/jgagnon/workspace/java/e1-task-info2/src/main/java/com/mycompany/e1tasks/backend/util/ExcelFileIngester.java:[11,37] package com.mycompany.exceljson.pojo does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/jgagnon/workspace/java/e1-task-info2/src/main/java/com/mycompany/e1tasks/backend/util/ExcelFileIngester.java:[12,37] package com.mycompany.exceljson.pojo does not exist
```

I've done research (including in this forum) and found numerous items on this issue. I've taken some of the advice found, but it still doesn't work. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the scenario:

Project A provides functionality that Project B needs to use.

Project A pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>excel-to-json</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Excel to JSON Converter</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
    <commons-cli.version>1.4</commons-cli.version>
    <org.apache.poi.version>4.1.2</org.apache.poi.version>
  </properties>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>${org.apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>${org.apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-cli.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Project B pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>e1-task-info2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
      <artifactId>excel-to-json</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

When I build my maven projects I almost always use `mvn clean install`. I've gone as far as completely removing my `~/.m2/repository` and rebuilding, but it still fails.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use spring-boot projects as dependencies. So you need to change the parent POM of your dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation explains, a spring boot project isn't suitable as a dependency for the projects, as the class files are placed somewhere where they can't be seen by the other project, in BOOT-INF/classes: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html

Comment: OK, so then what do I do? Do I need to refactor the dependency project to be non-Spring Boot? What other options are there?

Comment: What I found that works is adding `<attach>false</attach>` to the spring boot plugin configuration. I had tried adding a classifier, but that did not work.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-disable-attach.html

Comment: Note that doing that means that your executable isn't deployed to your maven repo.

Comment: I assume you mean any executable of the dependency (project A)? If so, no problem. It's really meant as a utility to be used by other projects and not something that would be run by itself.

Comment: That's OK then -- perhaps you don't need the repackage goal at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226295/discussion-between-joseph-gagnon-and-tgdavies).